# The ring of integers modulo $0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, congruences

I am studying the ring of integers modulo $n$, $\mathbf{Z_n}$, which consists of the set of all cosets $\overline{a}$ and the latter is the set of all the elements $b\in{\mathbf{Z}}$ such that $n|a-b$.

The ring $\mathbf{Z_2}$ is equal to the set of cosets {${\overline{0},\overline{1}}$}; the set $\mathbf{Z_1}$ is equal to {$\overline{0}$}=$\mathbf{Z}$.

I am confused in finding $\mathbf{Z_0}$. In my opinion it is the empty set since the division by zero does not make sense.

But by the first isomorphism theorem it follows that $\mathbf{Z_0}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z/0Z}$=$\mathbf{Z}$ which means that $\emptyset$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}$?

> What is the set $\mathbf{Z_0}$ equal to?

Would you help me please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You aren't dividing by zero. You're just quotienting by the equivalence relation of being divisible by zero. The only integer which is divisible by zero is $0$ (although $0/0$ still doesn't make sense, unfortunately), so $0\mathbb{Z}$ consists only of $0$ and hence you just get $\mathbb{Z}$ back.

Comment: This depends on how you write the divisibility relation in this context. It surely isn't a Euclidean division. But if you write it as $\exists k,\,a-b=k\cdot 0$, the congruence relation is just equality, and you obtain $\mathbf Z/0\mathbf Z=\mathbf Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say that $a \equiv_n b$ if $a - b = kn$ for some nonzero integer $k$.  Then $\equiv_n$ is the usual equivalence relation modulo $n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.  On the other hand, $\equiv_0$ can be made sense of, whereas "division by zero" doesn't really make sense.

Specifically, $a \equiv_0 b$ if $a-b = k0$ for some nonzero integer $k$.  But this means that $a-b = 0$, which implies that $a=b$.  Hence $\overline{a} = \{a\}$ for each $a\in\mathbb{Z}$.  This implies that $\mathbb{Z}_0 = \{\overline{a} : a\in\mathbb{Z}\} \cong \mathbb{Z}$, where the isomorphism is the obvious choice.